# regex_search in Ansible to return substring

Tags: ansible

I want to grab the string after the `CN=` in each of the strings below, and nothing else:

```
"CN=*.company.com,O=WWT,L=STL,ST=Missouri,C=US",        
"emailAddress=root@localhost.localdomain,CN=localhost.localdomain,OU=IT,O=MyCompany,L=Seattle,ST=WA,C=US"
```

I want `*.company.com` and `localhost.localdomain`

I think I'm close, but I'm getting more returned that I want:

```
(ansible)  ➜  ~ ansible --version
ansible 2.10.17
```

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  gather_facts: false
  vars:
    str1: "CN=*.company.com,O=WWT,L=STL,ST=Missouri,C=US"
    str2: "emailAddress=root@localhost.localdomain,CN=localhost.localdomain,OU=IT,O=MyCompany,L=Seattle,ST=WA,C=US"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        msg:
          - "{{ str1 | regex_search('CN=(.*),(.*$)', '\\1', '\\2') }}"
          - "{{ str1.split(',') | regex_search('CN=(.*)', '\\1') }}"
          - "{{ str2 | regex_search('CN=(.*),(.*$)', '\\1', '\\2') }}"
          - "{{ str2.split(',') | regex_search('CN=(.*)', '\\1') }}"
```

```
(ansible)  ➜  ~ ansible-playbook test2.yaml
[WARNING]: No inventory was parsed, only implicit localhost is available
[WARNING]: provided hosts list is empty, only localhost is available. Note that the implicit localhost does not match 'all'

PLAY [localhost] *******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [debug] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": [
        [
            "*.company.com,O=WWT,L=STL,ST=Missouri,",
            "C=US"
        ],
        [
            "*.company.com', 'O=WWT', 'L=STL', 'ST=Missouri', 'C=US']"
        ],
        [
            "localhost.localdomain,OU=IT,O=MyCompany,L=Seattle,ST=WA,",
            "C=US"
        ],
        [
            "localhost.localdomain', 'OU=IT', 'O=MyCompany', 'L=Seattle', 'ST=WA', 'C=US']"
        ]
    ]
}

PLAY RECAP *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

Comment: What is the expected output?  My guess is that you want `.*CN=([^,]+).*` but it's not clear.

Comment: Original Post amended.  The only thing I want is betwee CN= and the next comma.

Comment: You guessed exactly what I wanted, and that is working.  Thank you, Allan!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use this regex to match everything after the `CN=` with an optional prefix and exclude the matching of the comma `[^,]+` and then just ignore the tail:

```
.*CN=([^,]+).*
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the strings to dictionaries and get the attributes

```yaml
dict1: "{{ dict(str1|split(',')|map('split', '=')|list) }}"
dict2: "{{ dict(str2|split(',')|map('split', '=')|list) }}"
```

gives

```yaml
  dict1:
    C: US
    CN: '*.company.com'
    L: STL
    O: WWT
    ST: Missouri
```

```yaml
  dict2:
    C: US
    CN: localhost.localdomain
    L: Seattle
    O: MyCompany
    OU: IT
    ST: WA
    emailAddress: root@localhost.localdomain
```

---

**Notes**

1. Example of a complete playbook for testing

```yaml
- hosts: localhost

  vars:

    str1: "CN=*.company.com,O=WWT,L=STL,ST=Missouri,C=US"
    str2: "emailAddress=root@localhost.localdomain,CN=localhost.localdomain,OU=IT,O=MyCompany,L=Seattle,ST=WA,C=US"

    dict1: "{{ dict(str1|split(',')|map('split', '=')|list) }}"
    dict2: "{{ dict(str2|split(',')|map('split', '=')|list) }}"

  tasks:

    - debug:
        var: dict1
    - debug:
        var: dict2
```

2. Optionally, use *regex_replace*

```yaml
cn1: "{{ str1|regex_replace('^.*CN=(.*?),.*$', '\\1') }}"
cn2: "{{ str2|regex_replace('^.*CN=(.*?),.*$', '\\1') }}"
```

gives

```yaml
cn1: '*.company.com'
cn2: localhost.localdomain
```

3. The other option is the filter [*community.general.jc*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/community/general/docsite/filter_guide_conversions.html#converting-to-json)

```yaml
dict1: "{{ str1.split(',')|join('\n')|community.general.jc('ini') }}"
```

Comment: Thank you, Vladimir!  Another approach, though I don't think this works for me using Ansible 2.10 with the split filter, which I believe is available as of 2.11 or higher.

Comment: Use *community.general.jc*. I added an example.